# Accessing data in NSMutable Array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios6

I have an app where I write to a database using core data. This is working as I can see there is data in there using the SQLLite database browser. I am then retrieving the data into an NSMutable Array and I can see there is 1 record in debug mode using:

```
Print self.schoolNames.count
```

but I can't seem to read the array. My line is:

```
obsSchoolName = [[self.schoolNames objectAtIndex:0] obsSavedSchoolName];
```

where the attribute name of the field I am trying to access is obsSavedSchoolName.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: What is your problem? Does the compiler not find the method obsSavedSchoolName in any visible interface of <id>?

Comment: "No known instance of obsSavedSchoolName". If I am in debug mode and trying Print [[self.schoolNames objectAtIndex:0] obsSavedSchoolName] the error is "error: no known method '-obsSavedSchoolName'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression"

Comment: It does compile but it does not debug? Strange.

Comment: obsSavedSchoolName is a method of some class. Some subclass of NSManagedObject I suppose? However, that does not matter much. But you should have included the header file of that very class in the .m file in which you are accessing the method.

Comment: no - it will not compile. I have commented out the bad line and entered debug mode to try and figure out how to access the array. The error if I try and compile is  "No known instance of obsSavedSchoolName" and yet this is the attribute of the core data entity.

Comment: Did you include the .h file in question? If so then do it in two steps. First declare a temp var of the class of that object and assign [self.schoolNames objectAtIndex:0] to it and then send obsSavedSchoolName to that temp var.

Comment: Sorry I may not have been clear. The array is called schoolNames. It has one record in it and one field called obsSavedSchoolName. I can see the count is one but I can't seem to access the data in it.

Comment: You have got no problem accessing the first record. Accoring to the error message the problem is by accessing the method obsSavedSchoolName for any reason. Most likely is that the compiler cannot identify the class type of the records of the array schoolNames. And if you ask me - the compiler is right. Every object of type id could be a the first index of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your subclass of NSManagedObject is named "School". Then do:

```
#include "School.h"

...

School *tempSchool = [self.schoolNames objectAtIndex:0];
obsSchoolName = [tempSchool obsSavedSchoolName];
```

or

```
obsSchoolName = [(School*) [self.schoolNames objectAtIndex:0] obsSavedSchoolName];
```

Comment: You have reminded me of a step I have missed. I have not created the .h and .m file from the core data model. Perfect - thank you so much.

Comment: Or simply:`obsSchoolName = [(School*) [self.schoolNames[0] obsSavedSchoolName];
`

Comment: Ah, es. I too create the model objects from core data. If you don't then you can access the data directy from NSManagedObject in an alternative way, similar to fetching key value pairs from NSDictionarys. I just perfer it this way although in most cases this is more work.